# c# websocket console application on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: c#, azure, websocket, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a c# websocket code that will do the handshake and after successful, take the input from the client and return it back to the client again.

The code is working on localhost:8080 on my local machine.

I have an azure VM running Windows Server 2012 R2. I have created an Inbound Firewall Rule to allow connections on port 8080 on the server, and in azure. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to run(or host) c# console application on my server?
2. If yes, is there anything I am missing besides creating inbound firewall rule?
3. If no, what are the other options (windows service maybe)?

Right now, when I run the console app and run the client on my server, onOpen() function gets fired and the console app gets the message. However, the message is not the first GET request for websocket connection. Its something else, it gibberish. Hence I dont get the key and nothing works.

What am I doing wrong or missing? Please help!

Also, I have to be able to send message from the client to the server via websocket from the outside world.

Thank you

Comment: if you install console appliction on server you can not access directly it from the outside of console, windows service is also not option its limited to system or network . in order to access it from out side world you have to create webservice.